# Test whether a log message is generated using Boost.Log

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

I am currently using Boost.Log in one of my software projects. There is one case, where I report an error condition by using a log message. I would like to test whether this condition is detected correctly using google testing framework. Just to be clear, I want to test whether the message is generated. It may be removed by a filter, but this should not cause the test to fail. Is this possible at all? Any hints? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For base yes-or-no testing, simply use `assert`, something like this:

```
#include <assert.h>     /* assert */

void print_number(int* myInt) {
  assert (myInt!=NULL);
  // Boost.Log stuff...
  // print_number stuff...
}
```

this will give you a straight up message (depending on compiler/OS) if the test fails.

Comment: The solution is not quite as general as I had hoped for (e.g. testing for warnings), but works for the case at hand. Thanks for setting me straight, I was so focused on the possibility of detecting that log message that I did not consider the obvious solution! I'll accept your answer later on in case no one shows up with a more general one.

Comment: You can also easily disable for production code with a simple `#define NDEBUG ` seen (i.e in your general header or in the makefile/command-line) before the `#include <assert.h>`